# Application has two different back buttons with different functions

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a activity with a fragment in it. User taps on one item in a recyclerview and opens the secon activity (a fragment too). The second activity has a back button in the toolbar. When the user taps the "Back" Key on the devices bottom, it goes back to the first activity and restores the position from the items with

```
prefs.getInt("position", position);
if (position < 0) {
    ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).scrollToPosition(position);
}
```

Which is set in my onResponse Method (JSON Parsing with Retrofit).
That works. But if the user taps the back button in the toolbar, it goes back to the first activity but reloads all the code an ignores the position setting.

How can I achieve the same effect the back button on the device with the button in the toolbar?

Comment: Can you share your codes?

Comment: You should paste the code which handles the back key/button event.

Comment: @zdd I only used the "new Activity" template and selected that there has to be a back button. In my code from both activites I can?t find any codes relating to the back button